# How to create dynamics meta tags in metaInfo - vue spa?

Tags: vue.js, meta-tags

I should use a condition to create dynamic meta tag but don't know how to do it! I searched in google but didn't get any result

I tried to use a method in `metaInfo` but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try [**vue-head**](https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head) module.

**Install:**

```
npm install vue-head --save
```

**Import:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueHead from 'vue-head'

Vue.use(VueHead)
Vue.use(VueRouter)
...
```

**Example:**

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      title: 'My Title'
    }
  },
  // Usage with context the component
  head: {
    // To use "this" in the component, it is necessary to return the object through a function
    title: function () {
      return {
        inner: this.title
      }
    },
    meta: [
      { name: 'description', content: 'My description', id: 'desc' }
    ]
  }
    ...
  }
}
```